# How to create automatic email trigger using SharePoint site when the specified date arrives?

Tags: office-2016

To generate the automatic email based on particular cells date

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about a modern SharePoint you can build a flow for that.

Create a scheduled flow running once every day.

Get the items from your list and check if the reminder date is reached. If yes, send an email.

The formular in the condition is **[YOUR DATE FIELD]** is equal to **formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')**

[image]